# How to write a list in the URL and pass it to an MVC controller in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I need to be able to write a list in an URL that is mapped to a controller which then does something on the list. As an example:

i go to
http://localhost:8080/API/ControllerID/Action/a,b,c,d

which i would like to parse to a controller that looks like:

```
public ActionResult Action(List<string> ListItems)
{
    // do something on the list
}
```

And the maproute looking somthing like this:

```
context.MapRoute(
     "ListActions",
     "API/{controller}/{action}/{ListItems}",
     new { controller = "", action = "", ListItems = ""}
);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, possible. Use different delimeter, e.g. "-", whatever doesn't break logic.
in controller you can split string via String.Split.

Answer (score 0):

And don't do that, Plz! From security perspective having or letting long URL's is not safe at all + IIS will/can restrict that.

Comment: Why not? What if want to dispay both categories of my eshop item? Shooes-Hats. Is it unsafe? It more readable for end user.

Comment: It's for an internal API only used by trusted sources, with machine generated URL's. Hence security is a non-issue in this part of the application.